# Trying out icons in HTML5, they are not showing

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome, cdn

I was following "Introduction to HTML5" by University of Michigan on Coursera. They were adding icons from Font Awesome and I tried it too, I got my cdn(not sure if this means what I think it means?) from the first google result and just copy pasted the entire `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` part. Instead of the icon, this [![F082 in a box][1]][1] appeared. It does link me to the correct page just that the icon isn't showing. I tried disabling my adblock for both websites but it still doesn't work.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>MY FIRST PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <main><p>THIS IS MY MAIN CODE</main>
    <footer>
        <p>THINK OF A MORE INTERESTING FOOTER

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" aria-label="facebook">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
        </a>

    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNBo5.png
```

Comment: You are including Font Awesome 4.7 but you are using the classes for FontAwesome 5. See here for the 4.7 icons: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Comment: Us kittens have to look out for one another ;)

Comment: Hi kitten do you think you can help me out with this? :D
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122695/cost-function-not-decreasing-after-a-certain-number-of-iterations-logistic-reg

Comment: I don't know anything about machine learning, sorry :(